# Constructing a family of $3$-wise independence functions from $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, finite-fields, random-functions

A family of function hash functions $\mathcal{H}:\{h:N\rightarrow M\}$ is call $k$-wise independent if whenenver $h$ is drawn uniformly from $\mathcal{H}$, let $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ be distinct elements of $N$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_k$ be any elements of $M$, the following holds:

$\begin{equation}Pr[h(x_1)=y_1,\ldots,h(x_k)=y_k] = \frac{1}{|M|^k} \end{equation}$

Like my question suggest, I am wondering how to construct a family of $3$-wise independence functions from $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$.

The paper https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=6fc61778986560499651facab4090decd382236d
is successful in the construction when $p=2$, but the argument does not hold when generalize over arbitrary finite fields.

Thus I was wondering if anyone know any papers or avenue that I can pursue to further my investigation.

Cheers

Comment: Can't you construct a k-independent hash $F_{p^n}\to F_{p^n}$ (by randomly choosing the coefficients of a polynomial, for instance) and then apply some equidistributed function $f: F_{p^n}\to F_p$?

Comment: is the answer now satisfactory?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathrm{tr}:GF(p^n)\rightarrow GF(p)$ be the trace function which is equidistributed. Choose a basis so that you consider $GF(p^n)$ as the vector space $GF(p^n)$. For any $c \in GF(p^n)^\ast,$ the map
$$
h_c(x)=\mathrm{tr}(cx)
$$
is equidistributed in $GF(p),$ so that
$$
\mathbb{P}(h_c(x_1)=y_1,\ldots,h_c(x_k)=y_k)=\frac{1}{p^k},\mathrm{~~provided~~}c\in GF(p^n)^\ast
$$
as required.

Comment: Is there a reference or text that I can look into ? I am curious to know more about this topic, so any material helps in this regard :)

Comment: I don't understand. The post asks for a family $H$ of functions, such that for any $x_1, x_2, x_3$, if you choose $h$ uniformly from the family $H$, then $h(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ is equidistributed on $M^k$. What would it mean for a _single_ function $h_c$ to have that property? Or for that matter three functions $h_{c_1}, h_{c_2}, h_{c_3}$?

Comment: @JamesMartin, I am parametrizing a set of functions by the nonzero constant $c$.

Comment: Thanks for rewriting @kodlu. I still don't get the last sentence: "In fact if you choose $h_{c_1},h_{c_2},h_{c_3}$ with three distinct nonzero constants $c_i$ you will get $3$-wise independence". I don't think you can get $3$-wise independence (according to the definition given in the post) with just $3$ functions $h_{c_1}, h_{c_2}, h_{c_3}$. To get $k$-independence over a set $M$, the size of your family must be a multiple of $|M|^k$.

Comment: I am not understanding as well, after I choose $h_c$ uniformly at random, the $c$ is fixed. I dont get how the claim : "if you choose $h_{c_1}$,$h_{c_2}$,$h_{c_3}$
 with three distinct nonzero constants c_i
 you will get 3−wise independence." fits the definition of $k$-wise independence i gave

Comment: Answer updated and cleaned up.